# Writing to a text file in AppData doesn't work - C#

Tags: c#, file, text, appdata

I'm using the following lines of code in order to write credentials of users to a text file. It's supposed to create the directory inside AppData (which it does) but it doesn't write the credentials to the text file, it leaves it blank!

```
public void RegisterUserCreds()
{
    string[] creds = { Username.Text, Password.Text };
    string roaming = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    if (!Directory.Exists(roaming + "/Launcher")) 
        Directory.CreateDirectory(roaming + "/Launcher");
    string specificFolder = roaming + "/Launcher/user_info.txt";
    var fs = File.Open(specificFolder, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    sw.WriteLine(Username.Text);
    fs.Close();
}
```

What's the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) when operating on streams:

```
public static void RegisterUserCreds()
{
    string[] creds = { Username.Text, Password.Text };
    string roaming = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    if (!Directory.Exists(roaming + "/Launcher")) Directory.CreateDirectory(roaming + "/Launcher");
    string specificFolder = roaming + "/Launcher/user_info.txt";
    using (var fs = File.Open(specificFolder, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(Username.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

In your code you were closing the file stream before the stream writer was able to flush the changes you want to write so the file was created empty.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the wrong stream.  When you create new stream objects and pass an existing stream to the constructor, that new stream now "owns" the old stream.  When you dispose of the newer stream it will automatically dispose of the older one.

In your situation, you're closing the "fs" stream, but the "sw" stream might not have actually written to it yet (it has it's own internal buffer).  If you were to close the "sw" stream instead, it would flush it's buffer (into the "fs" stream), and then it would call fs.Dispose() for you to make sure it did the same thing.

There's a much better way, that would help you avoid doing things out-of-order like this, as well as make sure you're calling `Dispose()` even if exceptions get thrown (streams implement `IDisposable`, so you're supposed to always call their `Dispose()` method when you're done with them so they can internally "clean up").  The `using` statement is perfect for this, since it will call `Dispose()` even if an exception is thrown (it's a shortcut for wrapping the code with try/finally blocks):

```
using (var fs = File.Open(specificFolder, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(Username.Text);
    }
}
```

This is the same as this:

```
try
{
    var fs = File.Open(specificFolder, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    try
    {
        var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine(Username.Text);
    }
    finally
    {
        sw.Dispose();
    }
}
finally
{
    fs.Dispose();
}
```

Even though `sw.Dispose()` will call `fs.Dispose()` for you, there is no harm in calling `fs.Dispose()` again.  Why is it important to call Dispose()?  Let's say an exception was thrown during `sw.WriteLine()` (e.g. out of disk space, I/O error, etc.)... the file would stay open until your app terminated.  The `using` (or the try/catch version) would make sure the file was closed no matter what.

(side note: with streams, `Dispose()` and `Close()` do the same thing, you don't need to call both.  `Close()` just calls `Dispose()` -- MS included a method called `Close()` because that was what people were used to with a file API, but the .NET `IDisposable` interface uses a method called `Dispose()`)

(another side note: starting with .NET 4.5, many of the stream classes have an additional constructor that has a new "leaveOpen" parameter... passing `true` would tell that stream to NOT dispose of the original stream automatically)